# How to do a correct redirect in validate()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this code:

```js
<template>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <HeaderApp>

      <DivHeaderMenu>
      </DivHeaderMenu>

    </HeaderApp>

    <CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp>
    </CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp>

    <FooterApp>
    </FooterApp>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
  //company_history
  import axios from 'axios';
  import HeaderApp from '~/components/HeaderApp';
  import FooterApp from '~/components/FooterApp';
  import CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp from '~/components/CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp'
  import DivHeaderMenu from '~/components/DivHeaderMenu';
  import Pixelperfect from '~/components/Pixelperfect';

  export default{

  fetch ({ store, params, redirect }) {
    return axios.get('http://seo-gmbh.eu/json/api_sunds.php?action=get_pages&url=company_history')
    .then((res) => {
      store.commit('company_history/init_data_for_firmenistorie', res.data);
    })
  },


validate({store, params, error, redirect}) {

    const urlData = ['2015', '2016', '2017'];

    let resultArray = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < urlData.length; i++) {
      if(params.id === urlData[i]){
        return resultArray = urlData[i];
      }
    }
    if(resultArray == false){
        return redirect('/Firmenistorie');
    }
},


  head () {
    return {
      title: this.$store.state.company_history.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.meta.title,
      meta: [
        {description: this.$store.state.company_history.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieData.data.meta.description}
      ]
    }
  },

  components:{
    HeaderApp,
    FooterApp,
    CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp,
    DivHeaderMenu,
    Pixelperfect
  }
}

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

I try to do redirect to page '/Firmenistorie' if my currently URL not equal one of those value:
['2015', '2016', '2017']

It works if I don't write slash with some value after it:

[image: http://joxi.ru/l2ZKbPRCz9ZJjA]

In this case, redirect works correctly.

But if I try to write this:

[image: http://joxi.ru/MAjdQLoHje757m]

Redirect is not work.
(404 error works correctly - but without any redirect)

Why is it happening?
How can I do redirect in my second case?

P.S. My files structure looks like that:

[image: http://joxi.ru/KAg5e6oHEwkQDm]